# Cannot click a button using Java and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have the following two buttons on a form I need to test:

```
 <div class="ef-buttons">

 <button value="next" name="action" type="submit">
  Continue
 </button>

 <button id="modify_button" value="previous" name="action" type="submit">
  Go Back
 </button>

 </div>
```

I want to click the Continue Button, for which I wrote the next piece of code:

```
    By chain = new ByChained(By.className("ef-buttons"),(By.xpath("//*[@value='next']")));
    driver.findElement(chain).click();
```

However, everytime I get the message Cannot locate an element. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend consolidating your `By`, and just using CSS.  It's faster and easier.  This is how you'd select your element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ef-buttons button[name='action']")).click();
```

FYI, it's better practice to use the `name` attribute over `value` since `name` is more unique.

Comment: The problem is, that both the NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons have the same 'name' attribute. However, changing it to [value='next']  did the trick! Tnx

Comment: HA! I didn't even catch that.  that's bad design, but i'm glad you figured it out! :)